# Python Pandas group by and exclude values based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with three columns ID, Col1, and Col2. I want to group the df by ID and Col1 and remove all values of Col1 which are lower than the value in Col2.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']},
                  {'Col1': [0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 2]},
                  {"Col2": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})

  ID  Col1  Col2
0  A     0     1
1  A     1     1
2  A     2     1
3  A     4     1
4  B     0     2
5  B     1     2
6  B     2     2
```

The end result should like this

```
  ID  Col1
0  A     1
1  A     2
2  A     4
3  B     2
```

I can do it by iterating over the dataframe and splitting it into chunks, but there must be a simpler and faster way to this with Pandas functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `groupby` is not necessary, use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) only with `loc` for filtering columns by names:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['Col1'].ge(df['Col2']), ['ID', 'Col1']]
#alternative
#df1 = df.loc[df['Col1'] >= df['Col2'], ['ID', 'Col1']]
```

---

```
print (df1)

  ID  Col1
1  A     1
2  A     2
3  A     4
6  B     2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html). `groupby` is not required since you are not performing an aggregation.

```
res = df.query('Col1 >= Col2')[['ID', 'Col1']]

print(res)

  ID  Col1
1  A     1
2  A     2
3  A     4
6  B     2
```

Comment: They both work perfectly, but the variant with the greater(ge) function is slightly faster. 
The other difference that I noticed is that you can't use column names containing empty spaces with query.

Comment: @1nfern0, Yup that's an issue with `query` syntax. But note for very large dataframes, you should find `query` faster.